# React Native - Apple Mach-O Linker Error

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I'm trying to open an existing React Native project on Xcode 8. When I build the project, It fails and I got this error: **Apple Mach-O Linker Error**. 
[image]
What I did before:

1. Run `react-native link`
2. Set **Enable Bitcode** to **No** in Build Settings
3. Deleted **Derived Data** folder and rebuild project
4. Clean and Build project again.

But none of them worked. Why is this happening?

Edit:

```
"dependencies": {
    "immutable": "^3.8.1",
    "parse": "git+https://github.com/allmaxgit/Parse-SDK-JS.git",
    "react": "16.0.0-alpha.6",
    "react-native": "0.43.4",
    "react-native-maps": "^0.16.3",
    "react-native-md-textinput": "^2.0.4",
    "react-native-navigation": "^1.1.16",
    "react-native-push-notification": "^2.2.1",
    "react-native-snackbar": "^0.3.6",
    "react-native-swiper": "^1.5.4",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^4.0.1",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.4",
    "redux": "^3.6.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0"
  }
```

Comment: did you run npm install

Comment: Yes I did @MohamedKhalil

Comment: what version for react native & react native map

Comment: did you use pods?

Comment: I edited my question. I'm using react-native 0.43.4 and react-native-maps 0.16.3

Comment: did you use pods for maps?

Comment: Yes I used pods. I installed it running `pod install` in `ios` project folder.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154365/discussion-between-mohamed-khalil-and-pirate-of-marmara).

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to run in Terminal? 
Any module that is no longer present cause this issue. Go to Xcode -> [your iOS build target] -> Build Phases -> Link Binaries with Libraries and remove it.